# Swift Playgrounds Error: Unrecognized Selector sent to instance (related to UITapGestureRecognizer)

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I keep getting the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel theUserClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd8c5404380'

I'm not very familiar with programmatically using `UITapGestureRecognizers` so any help would be great!
*Not all variables shown*

```
class NoteCard:NSObject {
   let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer
   let NoteCardView:UILabel

 init(cardValue:Int, vc:MainViewController) {
   NoteCardView = UILabel(frame: .zero)
   tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: NoteCardView, action: "theUserClicked:")
   NoteCardView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   NoteCardView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
 }
}

class MainViewController:UIViewController {

func theUserClicked(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let card:NoteCard = recognizer.view as! NoteCard
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        card.NoteCardView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: card.NoteCardView.leftAnchor, constant: (self.elementPlacement/4)+20).isActive = true
        card.NoteCardView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: card.NoteCardView.bottomAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    }, completion: { (true) in
        self.elementPlacement = self.elementPlacement + 1
        if self.elementPlacement == 5 {
            card.tap.isEnabled = false
        }

    })
}
}
```

Comment: Your `UITapGestureRecognizer's target` is wrong. Target will be the install of `MainViewController` that contains `theUserClicked`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel doesn't have a method declaration matching `theUserClicked`.

Instead, move the method `theUserClicked` in to NotesCardView and pass self to the UITapGestureRecognizer. Then, following the MVC pattern, create a delegate protocol for the MainViewController to conform to. Also, why not just use a UIButton?

I think you may be slightly confused about the MVC pattern. IMO, it looks like your trying to combine the model and the view.

I highly recommend reading about the patterns used in iOS. This way you can progress and write better code.

Here's a description, by Apple, about the MVC pattern: [Model-View-Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)

Here is an example of some code that may help you (May have some errors but, I'm sure you can fix them):

```
// Essentially, this is the command line version of the note card, 
// known as the Model. Based on personal opinion and problem domain, 
// put your business logic here or use a composition pattern with PO*Os 
// (Plain old * Language Name * objects).

public class NoteCard: NSObject
{
    internal(set) var cardValue: Int!

    required init(cardValue value: Int)
    {
        cardValue = value

        super.init()
    }
}

// This protocol is used to delegate "actions" to your ViewController.
public protocol NoteCardViewDelegate
{
    func noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(_ view: NoteCardView) -> Bool
}

// This class just represents what things should look like. That's it.
public class NoteCardView: UIView
{
    // This is the reference to the UIViewController or whatever may 
    // happen to need to use this view.
    @IBInspectable weak var delegate: NoteCardViewDelegate?

    // A content view will come in handy more than likely at some 
    // point. Plus, it's a common pattern to use. You might even want 
    // to use a stackView as well.
    @IBInspectable let contentView = UIView()

    // I'm not sure why you want to use a UILabel with a tapGestureRecognizer instead of a UIButton, but that's up to you.
    @IBInspectable let titleLabel = UILabel()

    internal var titleLabelTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?

    override func updateConstraints()
    {
        // add constraints for the contentView and titleLabel
        super.updateConstraints()
    }

    // We'll create a common initialization method to follow the DRY 
    // rule (Don't Repeat Yourself). Since we want to be able to use 
    // this view with Interface Builder. This will come in handy. 
    // Especially if we have more than one initialization method.
    internal func commonInit()
    {
        // add label and contentView

        self.titleLabelGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTitleLabelTap(_:))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(titleLabelTapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    // This method is called if you create an instance of this view in 
    // Interface Builder. It's a good idea to override it and call the 
    // commonInit.
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.commonInit()
    }

    override init(withFrame frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(withFrame: frame)

        self.commonInit()
    }

    internal func handleTitleLabelTap(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
         self.delegate?.noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(self)
    }
}

public class MainViewController: UIViewController { }

public extension MainViewController: NoteCardViewDelegate
{
    func noteCardViewTitleLabelDidRecieveTap(_ view: NoteCardView)
    {
        let card: NoteCardView = (recognizer.view as! NoteCardView)

         UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {

             card.titleLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: card.titleLabel.leftAnchor, constant: (self.elementPlacement / 4) + 20)
             card.titleLabel.leftAnchor.isActive = true

        card.titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: card.titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 100)
             card.titleLabel.leftAnchor.isActive = true

        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

            self.elementPlacement = (self.elementPlacement + 1)
            card.tap.isEnabled = !(self.elementPlacement == 5)
        })
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan! Thanks for your help. So my intention is to create Note Cards with a Letter in the middle that can be clicked and will animate one by one to the center of the screen, for a maximum of 4. I'm just unclear about the difference between the contentView and the NoteCardView and which one to add constraints and properties to show on the screen. Thanks in advance! Learning swift for the first time and this is SUPER helpful!

Comment: I would add constraints in the NoteCardView on the contentView. The contentView is for all of the content in the NoteCardView. When adding content add them to the contentView and then add the constraints on the contentView.

Answer (score 0):

Your tap gesture recognizer is `NoteCardView` whose class is UILabel. So `theUserClicked:` action will be sent to `NoteCardView`. To solve this, set target to a `MainViewController` instance. Or move that action function to an available class and make target an instance of that class.